# Does libyuv have a YUV420ToRGB565 function optimized for NEON?

Tags: colors, neon, libyuv

Does libyuv have a YUV420ToRGB565 function optimized for NEON?

From what I see in libyuv sources there's a function I420ToRGB565 but it first converts to ARGB and only then to RGB565 and that last conversion is not NEON-optimized. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, for the current r396 version.
I420ToRGB565 uses NEON for I420ToARGB but C for ARGBToRGB565.

Neon + C
I420ToRGB565_OptVsC (12649 ms)

Thats 12.6 ms/frame for 1280x720.  Its faster compared to just C:
I420ToRGB565_OptVsC (81485 ms)

RGB24 is 1 step NEON for comparison.
I420ToRGB24_OptVsC (3392 ms)

A bug is files to port to Neon
http://code.google.com/p/libyuv/issues/detail?id=103

Comment: Fixed in libyuv r452.
I420ToRGB565 is fully Neon (and SSSE3).

Comment: r479 adds RGB565ToI420 Neon optimized.